# Space problem in Xcode 4.0

Tags: objective-c, xcode, whitespace, space

I have installed a new xcode last night when i was checking for new functions.  There was a lock image next to the name of the files and above the editor on the right most side.  I clicked that lock and then i noticed that the space is replaced with some unknown character.  I have attached the image below. Now how can i remove these characters and make it normal space.  If anyone can help me out with this it will be great.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's really weird. Perhaps try Apple by email? Do these characters persist if you open the source file in another editor (e.g. emacs?)?

Comment: I don't think this is something you should be asking us.

Comment: yeah. i tried character encoding and text encoding also.  But that was not helpful..

Comment: @BoltClock: This is what i got.  When i click space button in xcode i get the same character which is shown in the image.  If you can help me out with this it will be great.

Comment: Menu>Editor>Hide Invisibles ?

Comment: guyz you can also mark the question as it is correct. and @BlackFrog: thats helpful i didnt knew that .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, so I write an answer, as it seems my comment was correct : )

You just need to disable to invisible characters.
Go the the menu > Editor > Hide Invisibles.

Note that you can also customize the keyboard shortcuts, so you're able to toggle the invisible characters on and off...

I usually do that, so I can quickly see if I have tabs or spaces, for instance...

Comment: Thanks! Got the WTF look  2 years later